# Можно ли в python сделать реакцию на "открытие" с помощью"?

Tags: python, проводник

Можно ли в python сделать реакцию на "открытие" с помощью"? То есть я допустим в проводнике открываю файл с помощью другой программы (своей) и как сделать так чтобы в этом случае выполнялось определенное действие с открытым файлом

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу сделать так чтобы можно было открыть файл (любой) с помощью моей программы, после чего выполнялось определенное действие с этим файлом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По факту, "открыть с помощью" просто передает файл как аргумент запуска. Значит можно использовать  `sys.args`.
Как пример:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
input()
```

После перетащил файлик с именем `file.txt` на мой `py`:

```
['D:\\Programs\\Python\\0.py', 'D:\\Programs\\Python\\file.txt']
```

Comment: Спасибо, помог!

Comment: @MenlisSmith отметьте ответ галочкой, если он вам помог